# What exactly does "Illegal instruction (core dumped)" mean?

Tags: linux-kernel, cpu, error-handling, intel, x86

I see a lot of solutions to resolving the problem exemplified by

> Illegal instruction (core dumped)

But, I'm wondering what exactly that means? What generates that error, and what's the root cause of it? Is that the CPU getting someone it believes is an instruction but can't decode? What happens under the hood to generate that error?

From `dmesg`, I see

```
[429572.598803] traps: test[4054] trap invalid opcode ip:400066 sp:ffac8cc0 error:0 in test[400000+1000]
[429758.598292] traps: test[4401] trap invalid opcode ip:400066 sp:ffa3f990 error:0 in test[400000+1000]
[430066.170626] traps: test[4854] trap invalid opcode ip:400066 sp:ff8ab000 error:0 in test[400000+1000]
[430439.855002] traps: test[5212] trap invalid opcode ip:8048071 sp:ffce2fa0 error:0 in test[8048000+1000]
```

Comment: Yes, the CPU generates an interrupt/trap/whatever the architecture calls it, and then a signal is raised as explained in the duplicate link.

Comment: Is it possible for you to run this `test` program under a debugger? There are several possible causes for SIGILL (a totally random illegal instruction due to memory errors, a `ud2` instruction intentionally inserted by the compiler, or a library function intentionally posting that signal), and it may be useful to see the actual instruction and stack trace that caused it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For the x86.** This on-screen error seems to be a result of `SIGILL` being sent by the kernel, which is a "CPU Trap" defined in `kernel/traps.c` to catch `X86_TRAP_UD`. It's one in a class of a [few others](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/958f338e96f874a0d29442396d6adf9c1e17aa2d/arch/x86/kernel/idt.c#L74) that are raised directly from the CPU that include,

```
X86_TRAP_DE,        divide_error
X86_TRAP_NMI,       nmi
X86_TRAP_BR,        bounds
X86_TRAP_UD,        invalid_op
X86_TRAP_NM,        device_not_available
X86_TRAP_OLD_MF,    coprocessor_segment_overrun
X86_TRAP_TS,        invalid_TSS
X86_TRAP_NP,        segment_not_present
X86_TRAP_SS,        stack_segment
X86_TRAP_GP,        general_protection
X86_TRAP_SPURIOUS,  spurious_interrupt_bug
X86_TRAP_MF,        coprocessor_error
X86_TRAP_AC,        alignment_check
X86_TRAP_XF,        simd_coprocessor_error
```

For amusement, you can see a [list of programs demonstrating this with Golf here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/100532/shortest-code-to-throw-sigill)